# parse not loading first images in tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform, uiimage

I am using parse to store and retrieve some data, which I then load into a UITableview, each cell contains some text and image, however when I open my tableview, any cells in the view do not show images until I scroll them out of view and back into view (I guess this is calling cellForRowAtIndexPath). Is there a way to check when all images are downloaded and then reload the tableview?

```
func loadData(){

    self.data.removeAllObjects()

    var query = PFQuery(className:"Tanks")
    query.orderByAscending("createdAt")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.

            for object in objects {
                self.data.addObject(object)
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog("Error: %@ %@", error, error.userInfo!)
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell {
    self.cell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath!) as TankTableViewCell  // let cell:TankTableViewCell

    let item:PFObject = self.data.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row) as PFObject



    self.cell.productName.alpha = 1.0
    self.cell.companyName.alpha = 1.0
    self.cell.reviewTv.alpha = 1.0



    self.rating = item.objectForKey("rating") as NSNumber

    cell.productName.text = item.objectForKey("prodName") as? String
    cell.companyName.text = item.objectForKey("compName") as? String
    self.cell.reviewTv.text = item.objectForKey("review") as? String

    let userImageFile = item.objectForKey("image") as PFFile




    userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
            self.cell.productImage.image = image
        }

        }, progressBlock: {
            (percentDone: CInt) -> Void in
            if percentDone == 100{

            }
    })


    self.setStars(self.rating)


    // Configure the cell...
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
        self.cell.productName.alpha = 1.0
        self.cell.companyName.alpha = 1.0
        self.cell.reviewTv.alpha = 1.0
        self.cell.reviewTv.scrollRangeToVisible(0)
    })

    return cell

}
```

Comment: I'm not use to iOS, however I have had a similar problem in Android before. I don't think your problem is with parse, but it with the fact you are getting your userImageFile in the background. I imagine it is loading the tableview with whatever data is there to begin with (nothing), then when you scroll away and scroll back again it reloads the data this time showing the image because it has retrieved it

Comment: this is exactly what I thought, I would like to know if anyone has a work around for it though. like reload the tableview once all images are downloaded? Is there any way to check when all objects are downloaded?

Comment: Sorry I've done exactly that in Android, but not in iOS. In effect what I did in Android was to reload the tableview inside the getDataInBackground function when it returned. Note though that with that kind of method, you have to ensure the current position in the tableview is kept the same when it has been reloaded.

Comment: Cheers for your help mate, unfortunately the getDataInBackground is in my cellForRowAtIndex function so it would always reload non stop, I'm sure there is another way round it but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you use `self.cell` and that you change that reference each time a cell is returned. So, when the images are loaded they are all set into the last cell to be returned, which probably isn't on screen (or at least not fully).

Really you should be capturing the cell in the completion block of the image download (and checking that the cell is still linked to the same index path).

Also, you should cache the downloaded images so you don't always download the data / recreate the image.

Comment: Thanks guys, that is all some good advice and I will try to implement something along them lines, it all kind of makes sense what you all are saying. I will post back with any results I have.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a delegate method in your UITableViewController that gets called by another controller class that fetches the images.  I doubt that's what you want to do though.

What you should do is initialize the cells with a default image, and have the cell controller itself go and fetch the image in the background, and update its UIImageView when the fetch completes.  You definitely don't want to wait around for all images to load before reloading the table because a.) that takes a long time, and b.) what if one fails or times out?

Once the cell has loaded its image, if it is swapped out by the recycler and swapped back in, you can simply get the cached image by calling `getData` instead of `getDataInBackground` as long as `isDataAvailable` is true.

Answer (score 0):

After your line:

```
self.cell.productImage.image = image
```

Try Adding:

`cell.layoutSubviews()` or  `self.cell.layoutSubviews()`

It should render the subview, or your image in this case, on the first table view.